# Error when trying to install Gradle Integration for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle-eclipse

I get this dependency error when I try to install Gradle Integration for Eclipse:

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Spring Dashboard (optional) 3.4.0.201310051510-RELEASE
(org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.feature.group 3.4.0.201310051510-RELEASE)
Missing requirement: Getting Started With Spring Integration 3.4.0.201310051510-RELEASE (org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted 3.4.0.201310051510-RELEASE) requires 'bundle org.codehaus.jackson.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Spring Dashboard (optional) 3.4.0.201310051510-RELEASE(org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.feature.group 3.4.0.201310051510-RELEASE)
To: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted [3.4.0.201310051510-RELEASE]
```

The system is Ubuntu 12.04 and the Eclipse version is 4.2 (Juno).

I followed these tutorials: [How to setup Gradle in Eclipse](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse,-Intellij-IDEA,-NetBeans%29)
and [How to install Gradle on Linux](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N10116)

How can I fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I don't have the same setup as you do, but experienced the same problem. I found that the Milestone build worked for me instead of the release build. Eclipse Update site:
http://dist.springsource.com/milestone/TOOLS/gradle

More info can be found here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/

I had also recently updated my Eclipse environment before installing gradle. That might also be needed for it to work.

I hope that can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the updates, I think the devs are working on that.I've submitted an issue (I was't sure though if it was my setup or something else) on github's eclipse-integration-gradle and you can [check it here](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/issues/25)

Comment: If you install gradle tooling only, and not install the 'optional' dashboard and UAA components it should be fine.

Comment: Yup, same problem. Milestone fixed it. Release did not work. Also, only choosing gradle tooling (not installing optional components) did NOT work.